# bash script multiple rsync after previous has finished

Tags: bash, backup, rsync

hi i want to create a backup rsync script, and i want to create a additional copy of the sate of one folder at the beginning of the month and compare the changes to the end of the month my questing:
ho can i run a rsync job after the previous has finished, so i don't delete the backup dir bevor i compared the changes and backed them up?

for now if have:

```
if [ $MONTH -eq 1] && [ $DAY -eq 1]; then
rsync -a --forece --ignore-errors --compare-des=$MONTH_COMPARE $EXCLUDE_STRING $SOURCE_LOC ssh $TARGET_DIR/$LASTYEAR/12 
rsync -a --forece --ignore-errors --delete --update $EXCLUDE_STRING $SOURCE_LOC ssh $MONTH_COMPARE
```

it is important, that the second you doesn't start bevor the fist one has finished

Answer (score 1):

Delimine both `rsync` commands with `&&` operator. 
This operator ensures, that the second command executes **only** if the fist one is finished succesfully (returns exit code 0).

So, your code will be

```
if [ $MONTH -eq 1] && [ $DAY -eq 1]; then
rsync -a --forece --ignore-errors --compare-des=$MONTH_COMPARE $EXCLUDE_STRING $SOURCE_LOC ssh $TARGET_DIR/$LASTYEAR/12 &&
rsync -a --forece --ignore-errors --delete --update $EXCLUDE_STRING $SOURCE_LOC ssh $MONTH_COMPARE
```

You can also put those `rsync` lines into standalone script and launch it with `cron` on desired time, so you would not need the date condition.

Comment: Also, chcek if third argument "--forece" is correct, I don't have an *nix machine right now, but it looks like a typo